# How to give a curve shape at the bottom of your jpeg/png image using html, cs or may be using svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am creating my own website, where I want to give some effect to my header image. My code is given below. I have styled my header using background image and liner gradient.

```
@mixin header-style {
  .header {
    padding: 0 3rem;
    height: 95vh;
    background-image: $gradient-primary, url(../../images/play-img--2.jpeg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top;
    color: $general-color;
```

Here is my image and I have tried to use path in svg to give some effect to my image as its shown in the blue color but not succeed.

Comment: tried `border-radius`  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border_rounded.asp?

Answer (score 1):

You can use border-bottom-left-radius and border-bottom-right-radius to set a border shape only in the bottom of the image. Just like this:

```
     @mixin header-style{
    border-bottom-left-radius:50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius:50%;
    }
```

see here the results: https://codesandbox.io/s/test-7tx631?file=/index.css;

Comment: No, I don't think so that resolve an issue as, I want an S curve at bottom.